# Level curves of exponential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, algebraic-curves

I have the following two-variable function:

```
f(x,y) = exp(-x^2-(y-1)^2)
```

And I need to compute/sketch the level curves for `exp(-1), exp(-1/4) and 1`. I'm not sure how to go about this, I'm not even sure what the range is so this is a bit daunting.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated,

Cheers :)

Comment: For the first one, simplify $\exp(-x^2-(y-1)^2)=\exp(-1)$ then sketch the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $e^{-1}$ you get $$x^2 + (y-1)^2=1$$ which is a circle.

For $e^{-1/4}$ you get $$x^2 + (y-1)^2=1/4$$ which is another  circle.

For $1=e^{0}$ you get $$x^2 + (y-1)^2=0$$ which is a point.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for your help! Just to confirm, you cancelled the exponents on either side, and divided by -1 for the first two instances?

Comment: Yes that is what I did